# Mysql timezone on windows 7 not updated

Tags: mysql, timezone, windows-7-x64

I'm using **Windows 7**

**Mysql 5.5.15**

running `set time_zone = "Europe/Moscow";`

I get `Error Number: 1298
Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Moscow'`

I update the timezone tables using the latest from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html
but after mysql server startup the time zone tables are still empty and the command still returns the same errors.

Does anyone faced similar problem?

Comment: similar problem here, but without solution http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/2HORyt7t4kCIDgQkWHPq

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

For those who faced the same problem - here is what I found.
I ran `show variables like 'datadir'`
and found out that my data files are stored in a different folder:C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\

and I was replacing files in C:\Program Files... folder initially. There was also the needed files present.

So finally everything went fine.

Comment: Thanks much for this.. spent close to an hour finding why the tables were empty even after copying the files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by following this steps.

- If your MySql 5.6 or below

download **timezone_2016f_posix.zip** from below link and unzip then replace all files to

> **e.g.** yourDrive:\mysql\data\mysql

**or**

- If your MySql 5.7+

download **timezone_2016f_posix_sql.zip** from below link and unzip then replace all files to

> **e.g.** YourDrive:\mysql\data\mysql

You will get all of zip file from this link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

**Note:** Your mysql data path will be changed depands on your mysql version or MySql setup or If you use XAMPP the your path will be like this **yourdrive:\Xampp\mysql\data\mysql**

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = <timezone>;
```

Comment: the same error #1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Moscow'
 
the problem is that tables related to time_zone are empty in DB, although the files like time_zone_name.MYD contain data

Comment: yes, this was exactly where I started from. I posted solution which I found and what I did wrong, thanks.