# CONVERT_TZ function not working: Time zone data for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone, convert-tz

I am trying to use the CONVERT_TZ in MySQL. From what i have looked up the time_zone tables in the mysql schema need to be populated. I have looked this up on many different site and followed a few tutorials including [this tutorial](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/populate-time-zone-data-for-mysql.html) but the tables are still not populated

The 15 timezone files have been added to my `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql` directory.I have tried both to add these files manually and use the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454304/convert-tz-returns-null). I have restarted the MySQL service but the tables have still not been updated both ways

Does any have any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

I found the answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144250/mysql-timezone-on-windows-7-not-updated). It seemed that even do I had a folder structure of `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` when i ran the command `show variables like 'datadir` in MySQL it was pointing to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` which is a hidden folder so i did not see it before

When i added the timezone files to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql` it worked